# How can i deselect the unselected buttons

Tags: iphone

Iam developing one application.In that iam placing the radio buttons(uiimageview) on table view and apply the gesture effect.i am able to change the selected button image.But how can i change the un select button image.My code in gesture selector methd is looks like

```
-(void)cellchange:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
UIImage *cellselect=[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_on_1.png"];
UIImage *cellunselet=[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_off_1.png"];
 UIImageView *img=(UIImageView *)recognizer.view;
for(int k=0;k<[ages count];k++)
{

    if(img.tag==k)
    {
        UIImage *selectimg=img.image;
        if([selectimg isEqual:cellselect])
        {
            img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_off_1.png"];

        }
        if([selectimg isEqual:cellunselet])
        {
            img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_on_1.png"];
        }

    }
     }
    }
```

so please tell me how to change the unselected buttons images.

Comment: is this button or only the image??

Comment: why you are not using button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the better way would be using 'Button' instead of 'Image'. When tapped check whether it is in selected mode or unselected mode, then set image for button accordingly!